Why has HTTP3 more overhead?
I did some testing of HTTP3 and got the surprising result that HTTP3 has more overhead for single requests than HTTP1.1 or HTTP2. Surprising, as it is advertised the other way round.
What I did was using curl (version 8.8.0 with HTTP3 support compiled in) against different servers and monitored the network transfers using tcpdump.
I used the --http1.1, --http2, --http3 options of curl respectively to force direct usage of the desired HTTP version. (I checked that there aren't any TCP packets at all with --http3, it really uses HTTP3 directly.)
It tried it against a self-hosted NGINX 1.26.0, google.com and the example server of python-aioquic (http3_server.py).
From my self-hosted servers I transfered just a 5-byte dummy file, for Google I asked for https://google.com/x (resulting in a 404 and some blurb).
This is what I get:
Number of packets:



Server
http1.1
http2
http3




NGINX
19
21
25


python http.server / aioquic
14

15


Google
20
32
28



Total bytes transferred:



Server
http1.1
http2
http3




NGINX
4502
4538
10394


python http.server / aioquic
2279

4955


Google
9804
9946
13701



Any ideas what is wrong here?

Was fewer bytes for a single request a development goal? That sounds unlikely; single requests is a rare occurrence. Most real HTTP traffic is multiple requests, and increasingly spread out in time.

I understood it basically was. Or to be exact it was to be quicker to first deliver payload data on creating a new connection. Which on a high latency link depends a lot on the number of messages (roundtrips). That the number of roundtrips is lower was an explicit claim for QUIC.

Yep - and you show nothing that contravenes that number of roundtrips are less.

Hmm, you might have a point there, number of roundtrips != number of messages / 2.

Seems actually multiple messages are sent from the same side in sequence. Not sure if it is the right way of counting, but if I combine these into 1, it would make it 3 roundtrips for HTTP3 vs. 6 for HTTP1.1.
Still strange why it more than doubles the number of bytes transferred and splitting the data into more packets.

Number of round trips can't be inferred from the number of packets. Broadly speaking you will have to look at how many (blocking) requests the clients makes. Furthermore, you could count RT of TCP/IP packets as well; as QUIC uses UDP. It's not entirely straight forward, but you should compare performance for a typical use case, not a single request.

What would be a typical use case here? Making many requests over the same connection likely would result in no meaningful difference between the protocols as each additional request will be 1 RT and a small number of bytes overhead for TLS, flow control, etc., no? What I'm actually interested in is reducing server/network load for may clients, each making few requests. and there the determining factor should be number of packets and bytes transferred.

Modern websites will typically have tens or hundreds of requests for resources. Pipelining and earlier establishment of TLS, use of UDP, non-blocking behavior and so forth means less round trips. Benchmark what a typical client does.
